# How to implement logger in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, logging

I'm trying to implement logger for Excel, which WONT logg user changes to cell values (who cares...).

But internal dynamics of my app.

So:

1. It must be sheet based. (Cause user wont be able to remember to
   attach some strange files from strange locations...)
2. It must be easily excel-able. (Excel is quite good at simple analytics, right?
   I do not want to write any custom parser for logs. Just use built in
   functionality of Excel)
3. It must be elastic, when sometimes I will
   log additonal info, sometimes those will be variables, sometimes
   arrays, objects, etc.

Q: How to handle 3)? ParamArray will treat incoming array as single element. While using Array/Collection require preprocessing of scalar values into one item arrays/collections when loggin.

Here is my code so far:

```
Public Sub Log(level As LoggerSeverityLevel, functionName As String, message As   String, Optional Arguments As Variant)
Dim sh As Object
Set sh = ActiveSheet

LoggerDB.Activate
''' Find blank row for next entry
Dim firstEmptyRow As LongLong
firstEmptyRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1

''' Parse level into human redable format
Dim lvlMessage As String
lvlMessage = "Unknown"
If level = lslInfo Then lvlMessage = "Info"
If level = lslWarning Then lvlMessage = "Warning"
If level = lslDebug Then lvlMessage = "Debug"
If level = lslCritical Then lvlMessage = "Critical"

''' Insert data
LoggerDB.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 1) = Now()
LoggerDB.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 2) = lvlMessage
LoggerDB.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 3) = functionName
LoggerDB.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 4) = message

''' And optional arguments, one cell per argument
Dim i As Long
Dim arg As Variant
i = 4
For Each arg In Arguments
    LoggerDB.Cells(firstEmptyRow, i) = CStr(arg)
    i = i + 1
Next arg

sh.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: um what? ;) Want to have a quick read on [**Optional Parameters and ParamArrays**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/optional-parameters-and-paramarray-in-vba/)?

Comment: Nice. But it do not explain one important use case for me. I sometimes get array, and need to pass it to log function. How to handle that then? AFAIK it get stowed as ParamArrays(0) element. But how to handle that? I'm missing mechanism that would accept, nothing, value, values, array of values (or rather anything iterable by for each...).

Comment: you would iterate over each element in the ParamArray and possibly use `TypeName(*paramter*)` in a `Select Case` statement to work out what datatype your are handling.

Comment: Is there simple way to determine if variable is array/collection/other type iterable by for each?

Comment: Ok. I will go for InStr(TypeName(), "()") <> 0 Or TypeName() = "Collection Or TypeName() = Dictionary. That will cause bugs.. but should work for 99% of cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub Log(level As LoggerSeverityLevel, functionName As String, message As String,    Optional Arguments As Variant)
Dim sh As Object
Set sh = ActiveSheet

LoggerDB.Activate
''' Find blank row for next entry
Dim firstEmptyRow As LongLong
firstEmptyRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1

''' Parse level into human redable format
Dim lvlMessage As String
lvlMessage = "Unknown"
If level = lslInfo Then lvlMessage = "Info"
If level = lslWarning Then lvlMessage = "Warning"
If level = lslDebug Then lvlMessage = "Debug"
If level = lslCritical Then lvlMessage = "Critical"

''' Insert data
LoggerDB.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 1) = Now()
LoggerDB.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 2) = lvlMessage
LoggerDB.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 3) = functionName
LoggerDB.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 4) = message

''' And optional arguments, one cell per argument
Dim i As Long
Dim arg As Variant
i = 5
Dim tmp As Variant
Dim coll As Collection
```

This part pack scalars (number, string, bool, whatever single value) into collection.
So I can always assume that if any additional arguments are passed, For Each will work.

It relay on TypeName() returning string with "()" for arrays.

> If Not IsMissing(Arguments) Then
>           ' If not iterable by for each (single variable) pack into collection.
>           If Not (InStr(TypeName(Arguments), "()") <> 0 Or TypeName(Arguments) = "Collection" Or TypeName(Arguments) =
>   "Dictionary") Then
>               Set coll = New Collection
>               coll.add Arguments
>               Set tmp = coll
>           Else
>               tmp = Arguments
>           End If

```
    For Each arg In tmp
        LoggerDB.Cells(firstEmptyRow, i) = CStr(arg)
        i = i + 1
    Next arg
End If

sh.Activate
End Sub
```